# Apache Cordova Visual Studio 2015 Remotebuild iOS Release > Http 404: Installation failed: Check your provisioning profile

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2015, provisioning-profile, visual-studio-cordova, release-builds

When building in release mode for iOS with Apache Cordova for Visual Studio 2015, using a remotebuild mac server, I get the following error:

> 2>Http 404: Installation failed: Check your provisioning profile

My XCode Account has the provision profile and I've ensured that the  'ios_distribution.cer' (security certificate) has been added to the keychain.

[XCode Provisioning Profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MniRq.png)
[Certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WjTi.png)

I use XCode 7.2 and cordova CLI 4.3. I have a iPod Touch with iOS 9.2 plugged into the mac remote server. I've had no problems building for debug.

Have anyone else encountered this problem, and found a solution?

Comment: any luck on this problem?

Comment: i got it working , tell me if you need a help

Comment: Hi, Daniel - I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from remote build errors in VS. I’m hoping to chat with folks like you who have encountered issues with remote build and reached out to the community for troubleshooting. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. jomatthi [at] Microsoft [dot] com

Comment: @JordanMatthiesen we got this problem when we were exploring which platforms we should use for our future app development. We already have a lot of C# .NET and some javascript/typescript developers. So we were exploring several different ways of developing apps, where one of those were using Ionic and Cordova Apache. In the meantime we have shifted our app development to Xamarin, so unfortunately I do not think I would be the right person to interview since I no longer work with Apache Cordova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try building iOS release mode without deploying/running.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you missed anything. You might try following the detailed steps here:
http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#create-a-provisioning-profile

Comment: This guide only explains how to setup a Provisioning Profile for development. Not for distribution. Or am i missing something?